# Font-face suddenly stopped working

Tags: css, fonts

I got a problem and I beg you for an advice.
I was running a custom font on my blog for years, but few days ago it stopped working. Only Edge still can handle it. Here is my font-face cmd:

```
@font-face{

font-family: skolacek;
src: url(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=0B7-fhunaThR4RmctZXQ1WFVvazQ);

        }
```

The font file is called skolacek-ce.ttf. Could the "-" be the problem?

Also the 
`&amp;`
in the link is wierd, but blogger needs it.

Comment: that src url is not working?

Comment: Seems to be the &amp;

Comment: Thanks. So where to upload that font in order to get rid of the &amp;? I havent got any other storage.

Comment: don't you have drop box account?

Comment: Could it be this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39749953/font-face-suddenly-stopped-working

Comment: ok, ill try dropbox.

Comment: thank u very much, with dropbox it works. :)